# iAd Banner is messing up scene in SpriteKit

Tags: ios, sprite-kit, iad, adbannerview

I think I've looked through all the previous posts that are similar to this problem and couldn't find a solution so I hope someone can help me.

I've got a very simple game using SpriteKit. The game is in portrait mode only. When I view the game in the simulator, the ads appear perfect but they are on top of my content and have also shifted the top content off the screen so you can barely see the scores. I'm not sure if I need to do something in the ViewController or the scene itself that has the ads running, but I think the ViewController is the correct place.

I'm hoping someone else had this problem and figured it out. I saw some people say that using:

```
scene.scaleMode = SKSceneScaleModeAspectFill;
```

or

```
 scene.scaleMode = SKSceneScaleModeAspectFit;
```

changed their views to work. I'm using "fill" but I tried "fit" and neither seemed to do anything. Ideally the top of the banner is the new bottom of my screen and I can get everything to fit in the new smaller size but I'm kinda of stuck at the moment. Thanks for any help you can provide!

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and instead of using AspectFill or AspectFit
use this.

```
scene.scaleMode = .Fill
```

This option didn't cover up as much content as the others.